# How to Initialize Values for Optimization Algorithms?

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

I am interested using Gradient Based Optimization Algorithms (e.g. BFGS) for optimizing the Rastrign Function (over the range of (0,0) to (5,5)):

[image]

```
 Rastrigin <- function(x)
    {
        return(20 + x[1]^2 + x[2]^2 - 10*(cos(2*pi*x[1]) + cos(2*pi*x[2])))
    }
```

**Note:** the real minimum is (0,0)

I tried to do this using the R programming language, and noticed that the "initial values" can result in different outcomes. For example:

**Attempt #1 : (Start with (2,2)**

```
optim(par = c(2,2), Rastrigin, lower = c(-5,-5), upper = c(5,5), method = "L-BFGS-B")


$par
[1] 5.453531e-15 5.453531e-15

$value
[1] 0

$counts
function gradient 
       7        7 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
Attempt #2 : Start with (0,0)

 optim(par = c(0,0), Rastrigin, lower = c(-5,-5), upper = c(5,5), method = "L-BFGS-B")
$par
[1] 0 0

$value
[1] 0

$counts
function gradient 
       1        1 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: NORM OF PROJECTED GRADIENT <= PGTOL"
```

**Attempt #2 : Start with (0,0)**

```
 optim(par = c(0,0), Rastrigin, lower = c(-5,-5), upper = c(5,5), method = "L-BFGS-B")
$par
[1] 0 0

$value
[1] 0

$counts
function gradient 
       1        1 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: NORM OF PROJECTED GRADIENT <= PGTOL"
```

**Attempt 3: Start with (4.9, 4.9)**

```
optim(par = c(4.9, 4.9), Rastrigin, lower = c(-5,-5), upper = c(5,5), method = "L-BFGS-B")
$par
[1] 4.974691 4.974691

$value
[1] 49.74745

$counts
function gradient 
       5        5 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
```

**Attempt 4: Start with (0.01, 0.01)**

```
optim(par = c(0.01, 0.01), Rastrigin, lower = c(-5,-5), upper = c(5,5), method = "L-BFGS-B")
$par
[1] 1.813333e-11 1.813333e-11

$value
[1] 0

$counts
function gradient 
       6        6 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
```

As we can see, sometimes the choice of initial values can heavily throw the optimization algorithm away from the correct results. For instance, in **Attempt 3** convergence was reached, but a value of 49.74745 was returned instead of 0.

**My Question:** Is there a general consensus on how to select the initial values for an optimization algorithm?

In my case, the function being optimized only has 2 dimensions and we already know the true minimum value. Suppose if the function had many dimensions and we did not know the true value - how could we have selected the initial values for the optimization algorithm?

My naïve attempt would have been select the midpoint between the min/max range over which the function is being optimized. For example, if a 5 dimensional function is being optimized over (0,0,0,0,0) and (5,5,5,5,5) - I would have selected `(5-0/2, 5-0/2, 5-0/2, 5-0/2, 5-0/2)` has the initial value for the optimization algorithm.

**How are initial values generally chosen for optimization algorithms and why are they so important?**

Can someone please comment on this?

Thanks!

**References:**

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/optim

Comment: I wonder if [Operations Research SE](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions) might be a more relevant place for the question. Not to say it is off topic here, though.

Comment: I’d say there is no consensus, and finding good starting points is usually more art than science. Eg see my comment at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398072/is-there-a-square-with-all-corner-points-on-the-spiral-r-k-theta-0-leq-the#comment1025016_400817 about the hard part of the optimization being the selection of initial values.